# How to make two-way data binding by click?

Tags: angular

I have two input elements in one component and two paragraph elements in the other. When I typing a value in the Input, I immediately get it in the paragraph element because I use two-way data binding. But how can I make relation between two elements on click? I need the data from the input elements to be transferred to the paragraph elements **only after clicking on the button**.

My code:

**Main HTML**

```
        <div><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="names" /></div>
 <br/>
    <div>  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="age" /></div>

    <app-child [userName]="names" [userAge]="age"></app-child>

    <button (click)=???>Click</button>
```

**Child HTML**

```
<p>UserName: {{userName}}</p>
<p>Age: {{userAge}}</p>
```

**Main TS**

```
  names:string;
    age:number;
```

**Child TS**

```
  @Input() userName: string;
  @Input() userAge: number;
```

I will be grateful for any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With two way binding your child components values will always get updated on change in your parent component's properties. For your use you can create two more properties in your parent component, and assign value in them only on button click. Somewhat like this-

parent html-

```
<div><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="names" /></div>
<br />
<div> <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="age" /></div>

<app-child [userName]="uName" [userAge]="uAge"></app-child>

<button (click)="assignVal()">Click</button>
```

And in your parent component you can create a method to be called on the button click-

```
assignVal() {
    this.uName = this.names;
    this.uAge = this.age;
}
```

This should suffice.